# Creating a pointer of a pointer and modify it without modifying the original?

Tags: c++, singly-linked-list

Feel free to edit the title, engrish can sometimes confuse instead of help.

I have to make (**and no I can't change, this is the way it has to be**) simple linked list. ***NO I can't use STL or std::list***. Most of it is done, on paper, but I seem to have a problem implementing a very basic cursor.

This is my Node within the list (part of it):

```
struct Node {
    int ap_nr;
    Node *next;
};
```

I want to go trough the list in my add node function:

```
void add_node (Node **begin, int ap_nr)
{
     stuff happens
}
```

This is how I call the function:

```
add_node(&(*begin), ap_nr);
```

I want to create a cursor that starts from begin (the head of my list) and goes trough every node using `cursor->next` until I reach the end `(while (cursor->next!=0))`

but I can't simply say:

```
Node *cursor;
cursor = new Node;
cursor = begin;
```

Because this will simply overwrite cursor with begin, making my attempt invalid. I still have to make a pointer to begin and be able to call the STRUCT function "-> next"

How can I do this ?

*** ALSO *** How can I remember the previous Node ? can I do this:

```
Node *previous;
previous = new Node;
previous = &(*begin); // ?
```

Comment: `&(*begin)` is completely equivalent to `begin`, so why not use that one in the call to `add_node`?

Comment: First of all, usually 'iterator' is used in English discussion of C++ instead of 'cursor.' Secondly, you don't provide much information. Are you saying that you want to use a Node structure *as* an iterator, and also as a data container?

Comment: Every node is self-contained ... it has all the information it needs and the only modification I need to do is either add one or delete one (for the moment). I want a way of going from one node to the other (the list is nothing more than chained nodes) until I reach my goal (doesn't matter what that is) without losing my first node. I also tried simply `begin` but it did not work, `&(*begin)` worked so I'm not changing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to traverse the list in the `add_node` function.  If so then try the following

```
void add_node (Node **ppBegin, int ap_nr)
{
  if (!ppBegin) {
    // Need to handle the case of bad user data here
  }

  // Traverse until we get the to the empty next value
  while ((*ppBegin)->next) {
    ppBegin = &((*ppBegin)->next);
  }

  // ppBegin now points to the address of where the new node should go
  Node* created = new Node();
  created->ap_nr = ap_nr;
  *ppBegin = created;
}
```

Note: To call this function initially you should just call it with `add_node(&theListPointer)`.

Comment: wait, wouldn't `ppBegin = &((*ppBegin)->next);` move my begin, thus making me lose the "head" of my list ?

Comment: @Kalec no it wouldn't. C is a pass by value language so `ppBegin` is really a copy of the value provided to it. The modification to the list is only seen by the caller when you use a level of indirection such as i do in the `*ppBegin = created` line. Here I dig through the copy and reach the real shared value which is mutated

Comment: And `*ppBegin = created;` ? shouldn't I link this to the list somehow instead ? Because the list is a simple chain of linked Nodes, not an actual entity. What is this "created" ?

Comment: The `*ppBegin = created` line is linking it into the nodes. The trick here is that `ppBegin` is a `Node**`. It represents a pointer to the memory location where the new `Node*` must go.  It either points to the head of the `Node*` list (this is the state when the method is called) or to the last `next` value in the existing list.

Comment: Ok, I shall try and see if this works, but I'll be hones, I can't wrap my head around the idea that `Node **ppBegin` is the head of my list but `ppBegin = &((*ppBegin)->next);` doesn't change my head.

Comment: @Kalec i would encourage you to spend time and try and wrap your head around that. It's a fundamental concept of C. It's really hard to do this on a message board but the easiest way is to draw it out on a white board.

Comment: Any way, it worked, so I chose your answer (not that I had any others to chose from :P   ) Thank you a lot.